# How do I write many random files to separate drives using Bash?

Tags: bash, scripting

My current script looks like the following:

```
#! /bin/bash

for n in {1..10};
do
    dd if=/dev/urandom of=file$("$n").bin bs=1 count=$(( RANDOM + 1024 ))
done
```

It is only writing one file named "file{1..10}" and I have exhausted my limited scripting knowledge trying to fix it. Optimally, I would like to be able to use this script to write as many random files as I would like to any physical drive currently connected to the computer(sda, sdb, sdc).

Comment: Are you calling the script with `sh` from the command line, as in `sh scriptname`?

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Even in the bourne shell,  I don't think the behavior OP says would be reproduced, wouldn't it try to run no's 1-10 as a command?

Comment: @Inian I think so, but for `n` to ever contain `{1..10}` literally, something must be wrong there already.

Comment: check your `bash` version.  Brace range expansion is very old but until one point it wasn't in `bash`.  Relevant https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92819/why-is-brace-expansion-not-supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the $("$n") make execution which is not necessary:

```
#!/bin/bash

for n in {1..10}; do
    echo $n
    dd if=/dev/urandom of=file${n}.bin bs=1 count=$(( RANDOM + 1024 ))
done
```

Comment: of=/dev/sdb/file${n}.bin